# Why do I have to enclose bitwise operators, such as &,|,etc in a bracket, when I am displaying the output using cout?

Tags: c++

I am trying to display the output of bitwise operations directly through `cout` stream.

I am getting an error in such situations:

```
cout<<a|b
```

However, this seems to work,

```
cout<<(a|b);
```

In the case of arithmetic operations,

```
cout<<a+b;
```

and

```
cout<<(a+b);
```

works fine.

Note: I am considering `a` and `b` to be integers.

For example,

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
```

Can someone explain the reason behind this?

Comment: because [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` is also an operator, so "passing arguments to" `cout` doesn't really work the same way as a function. I put that in quotations because you are not passing arguments at all and it's not even a function. `cout` is an object with an operator overload defined for the `<<` operator.

When you have something like `cout << a | b;` you end up with `(cout << a) | b` due to [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The `cout << a` part is valid because `cout` has an overload for `<<`, so that part returns a reference to `cout`, and you end up doing `cout | b`, but `cout` has no overload for the `|` operator, so you get a compilation error.

Comment: And the reason for this is that `<<` is a repurposed bitshift operator (for which this precedence arguably makes much more sense) - we could say that this is a good reason not to repurpose operators in such a manner but there it is!

Answer (score 1):

because [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

`cout<<a|b` becomes `(cout<<a)|b`

while

`cout<<a+b` becomes `cout<<(a+b)`

Answer (score 1):

When parsing an expression, an operator which is listed on some row of the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator that is listed on a row further below it with a lower precedence.

For example, the expression `std::cout << a | b` is parsed as `(std::cout << a) | b`, and not as `std::cout << (a | b)`.

So in your example:
`cout<<(a|b)` works as intended because of parentheses but `cout<<a|b` will not.

But in the case of `cout<<a+b`, `+` has a greater precedence than `<<` and it works even without the parentheses as `a+b` is evaluated first.

So `cout<<a+b` is the same as `cout<<(a+b)`.